# I am not able to get out of this loop even after pressing y or no

Tags: c

I tried to run some C code (below):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int option;
    do {
        printf("Enter either y/n: ");
        option = fgetc(stdin);
        printf("\n");
    } while ((option != 'y') || (option != 'n'));

    printf("You Pressed Yes/No\n\n");
}
```

I don't know the actual issue but it's not getting out of the loop.
And one more thing, when i press any character either 'y' or 'n' or any character it prints the prompt two times or how many characters i enter into it
Please if some one can spare a moment and tell me where i am wrong it would be grateful. Thank You

Output:
[Output of the above code(Sorry for the link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEm3y.png)

Comment: If you press n, option!=y is true. So option will always not equal y or n

Comment: What you really want is `(option != 'y') && (option != 'n')`. Your current condition is always true.

Comment: @Suraj: can you accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score?

Answer (score 3):

You want to loop while `option` is different from `'y'` AND different from `'n'`.

Let's consider the following truth table:

```
 opt  | opt != 'y' | opt != 'n' | opt != 'y' OR opt != 'n' | opt != 'y' AND opt != 'n'
------+------------+------------+--------------------------+---------------------------
 'x'  |    true    |    true    |          true            |          true
 'y'  |    false   |    true    |          true            |          false
 'n'  |    true    |    false   |          true            |          false
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition in `while ((option != 'y') || (option != 'n'))` is always true.

You should write this test this way:

```
while ((option != 'y') && (option != 'n'));
```

Note that if you reach the end of the input stream, `fgetc()` will always return `EOF` and the loop will run indefinitely.  Fix this by also testing for `EOF`:

```
while (option != EOF && option != 'y' && option != 'n');
```

The reason you get multiple answers for a single input is `stdin` is line buffered, so you need to type `enter` to let the program receive the input.  This makes the full line of characters available to the program, including the trailing linefeed.

There is no portable way to turn off this line buffering, as it is actually performed by the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to continue looping as long as

   ```
   ((option != 'y') || (option != 'n'))
   ```
2. This means you want to leave the loop if the condition shown under 1 is not true, that is if

   ```
   !((option != 'y') || (option != 'n'))
   ```
3. Following [*De Morgan's Law*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) this (as per 1)

   ```
   ((option != 'y') || (option != 'n'))
   ```

   it the same as

   ```
   !((option == 'y') && (option == 'n'))
   ```

Inserting 3 into 2 leads to

```
!!((option == 'y') && (option == 'n'))
```

which is the same as

```
((option == 'y') && (option == 'n')
```

So you want leave the loop if `option` equals `y`and `n` at the same time. This obviously never will be the case. :-)